# how to fill the data class from xml file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

Early data lay in the application.yml file, but it was necessary to move it into a separate file to solve a parallel problem. The question is how to specify the path to this data.

I tried to change the path using PropertySource, but nothing really happened. Each time or data was taken from the same file or spring fell before it could start

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "merchant-connection")
data class ConnectionsProfileProperties(
    val connectionProfiles: Map<String, ConnectionProperties>
) {

    data class ConnectionProperties(
        val smser: SmserProperties,
        val two: TwoProperties,
        val masterPass: MasterPassProperties,
        val priority: PriorityProperties
    ) {
        data class SmserProperties(
            val host: String,
            val port: Int,
            val version: Int,
            val priority: Int,
            val dstHost: Int,
            val srcHost: Int,
            val phoneSrc: String,
            val socketTimeout: Duration
        )

        data class TwoProperties(
            val host: String,
            val port: Int,
            val useProxy: Boolean,
            val proxyHost: String?,
            val proxyPort: Int,
            val clerk: String,
            val password: String,
            val product: String,
            val retAddress: String,
            val version: String,
            val needDict: Int,
            val allVendors: Int,
            val avoidSession: Int,
            val readTimeout: Duration,
            val connectionTimeout: Duration
        )

        data class MasterPassProperties(
            val baseUrl: String,
            val consumerKey: String,
            val keyStorePath: String,
            val keyStorePassword: String,
            val keyAlias: String,
            val readTimeout: Duration,
            val connectionTimeout: Duration,
            val sessionTimeout: Duration,
            val needSendPhoneCheckDate: Boolean,
            val useSpecLogicMlccof: Boolean?
        )

        data class PriorityProperties(
            val regCardPriorityCof: CofName,
            val cardMatchPriorityCof: CofName,
            val sortCardPriorityCof: CofName,
            val delCardPriorityCof: CofName,
            val getCardInfoCof: CofName
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Your logic doesn't make sense... Why would you need to move it because of a parallel read? Seems like there is another problem you solved in a wrong way.

Comment: This is valid, but I am not particularly allowed to rewrite something that was written incorrectly. This pulls along such problems - @M.Deinum

Comment: Ehrm so instead of solving it correctly you want some dirty hack that might even make it worse? The reasoning just doesn't make sense, nor the XML part... If you want to load additional property files Spring Boot has support for that (which is pretty well documented and you don't need anything additional for that).

Comment: @M.Deinum Maybe I didn't get you right or you got me. Why do you think it's a "dirty hack" if I need to separate spring settings and "user" data.

Comment: There are just settings, like spring settings. The difference only exists in your head. Your question is mentioning a parallel issue, which is something with concurrency hence a dirty hack but apparently you meant you want to separate the properties. Spring Boot already supports that and as mentioned how to do that is documented pretty well in the official documentation. Hint something like `--spring.config.additional-location` as a parameter while starting, or adding it the the `SpringApplication` in the main method.

Comment: @M.Deinum I think I got your thought. I have no idea why this thought did not occur to me. Thank you for your help, but I feel slightly humiliated :))